# Multiple modal image popup on different triggers

Tags: html, bootstrap-modal

I used multiple svgs as my button to trigger the modal. How to reuse the same modal and display different images on different button and where should i place my img tag?

```
<g  id="Content1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#imagemodal">
   <--! svg code -->
</g>

<g  id="Content2" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#imagemodal">
   <--! svg code -->
</g>

<g  id="Content3" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#imagemodal">
   <--! svg code -->
</g>

<div class="modal fade" id="imagemodal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">              
      <div class="modal-body">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: [Varying modal content](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#varying-modal-content). Note you might want to change ids of your `<g>` elements to unique ones, so they can be selected by JavaScript and injected in the modal, as exemplified in documentation.

Comment: @tao Thanks for replying. The ids for <g> is a typo. I have read through the article you shared but i still cant figure out where should i insert my <img> tag so that my modal is showing my images.

Comment: You're showing empty `<g>` elements, but speak about non-existent `<img>`s. `<img>`'s don't work with `<g>`s. The do work wtih `<svg>` elements, inside which `<g>`s are valid elements (they're invalid in html). So, your first question is:"*How to use inline `<svg>` as `src` for an `<img>`?"* Your second question is *"How do I use variable content in a bootstrap modal?"*. Each of the two require research effort and one decent coding attempt on your part to be on-topic here. And each needs to be asked separately if they haven't been asked before on [so], which they have been, both.

Comment: Once you have the answers to the questions above, if, for any reason, you can't combine them, you might ask your current question, also providing a decent coding attempt and links to documentation stating your code should work according to your expectations. Without all of the above, your question is too much like a *"work for me for free"* (client's request) and too little like a *"help me understand why my code doesn't work as expected"* (coder's request).

Comment: @tao Thank you very much for the explanation. Will put more effort on my questions.

Answer (score 0):

A basic way of doing it:

```js
$('#imagemodal').on('show.bs.modal', function(event) {
  $(this).find('.modal-body')
    .empty()
    .append($(event.relatedTarget).clone())
})
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.m-c {
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.m-c>svg {
  width: 100px;
  height: auto;
  transition: transform .3s cubic-bezier(.4, 0, .2, 1);
  transform-origin: center;
  margin: 20px;
  transform: scale(.8);
}

.m-c>svg:hover {
  transform: scale(1.2);
}

.m-c>svg circle {
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: .42;
  transition: opacity .3s ease-out;
}

.m-c>svg circle:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.modal-body svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.modal .modal-content {
  background-color: #191919;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="container-fluid vh-100 d-flex align-items-center m-c">
  <svg version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 2 2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#imagemodal">
    <circle cx="1" cy="1" r="1" fill="red" />
  </svg>
  <svg version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 2 2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#imagemodal">
    <circle cx="1" cy="1" r="1" fill="green" />
  </svg>
  <svg version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 2 2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#imagemodal">
    <circle cx="1" cy="1" r="1" fill="blue" />
  </svg>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="imagemodal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

A few notes:

- it empties `.modal-body` and clones event's `relativeTarget` into it
- `event.relativeTarget` needs to be a valid HTML element (`<g>` isn't, so I used `<svg>`'s)
- if not obvious, the CSS is not required, it's aimed at this particular demo

Documentation:

- Bootstrap: [varying modal content](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#varying-modal-content), [modal events](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#events)
- jQuery: [.find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/), [.emtpy()](https://api.jquery.com/empty/), [.append()](https://api.jquery.com/append/)
- SVG: [<g>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/g), [<svg>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/svg)